# Show filtered data when no value is selected in slicer in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I have two tables, once for slicer and other one is for details table. The details table have a InvoiceDate column where some rows have blank InvoiceDate. The slicer table looks like below:

[image]

The slicer will only show value of of ID 1, like below.

[image]

Initially I want slicer to be un checked and the data should show only rows where InvoiceDate is Blank. Once User select the Slicer as Include Invoiced Records, it should show both full details i.e. Rows with Blank + Non-Empty dates rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two other ways of doing what you want that are probably more 'correct' but I'll also describe a way to provide the behavior you describe.

**Option one:**  Delete your second table.  Add a calculated column to your details table as follows:

```
Invoice Status = IF (ISBLANK([Invoice Date]) = TRUE(), "Not yet invoiced", "Invoiced")
```

Create a slicer using [Invoice Status] and simply default it to show 'not invoiced.'  If users want to see the invoiced records, they just check that box in the slicer as well.
[image]

**Option Two:**  Use Bookmarks and buttons to produce the desired effect.  Create two buttons, one that says 'Include Invoiced Customers' and another that says 'Hide Invoiced Customers' -- create two bookmarks where one has the invoiced customers filtered out of the visual and one where the invoiced customers aren't filtered.  Set each button's "Action" to the appropriate bookmark.

**Option Three**  Keep your 'slicer' table.  Let's assume it's called 'Invoice Filter Selection.'  Create a new measure:

```
IncludeDetailFilter = 

IF (ISFILTERED('Invoice Filter Selection'[Value]) = True(),
    1,
    IF (ISBLANK(MAX(InvoiceDetails[Invoice Date])) = TRUE(), 1, 0)
)
```

When the slicer has a selection, it will be considered 'Filtered' and you will pass into the first branch of the IF where the measure always evaluates to 1.   When the slicer isn't selected, the measure will evaluate to 1 or 0 depending on whether or not there are any values for Invoice Date in the row.  Add this new measure as a filter on your invoice detail visual.

Unchecked:

[image]

Checked:

[image]

Hope it Helps.